# Python. Keep values from for loop in a list

Tags: python, list

Dears,

How can I keep the values from a for loop into a list.

```
lista = list([])   

for x in datos[2572:2582]:

    if re.match('\d{3}-(.*?)Todas', (x[0])):
       lista = (x[0] + " FALSE")
       
    elif re.match('\d{3}-', (x[0])):
        lista = (x[0] + " TRUE")
        
    else:
        lista = (x[0] + " FALSE")
```

I would like to get a list 'lista' with the values upcoming from the previous code.

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting any errors with the current code?

Comment: What id the output that you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append()` adds elements to a list. For example, `lista.append(x[0] + " FALSE")`

Answer (score 2):

Though the question is not very clear, I assume this might be what you are looking for.

```
lista=[]
for x in datos[2572:2582]:

    if re.match('\d{3}-(.*?)Todas', (x[0])):
       lista.append(x[0] + " FALSE")
       
    elif re.match('\d{3}-', (x[0])):
        lista.append(x[0] + " TRUE") 

    else:
        lista.append(x[0] + " FALSE")
```